# PopOut a middle Image in a UIScrollView contain many images

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uiscrollview, xcode4.3, ios5

I have problem in playing with the UIScrollView i am using a customImage Object class to display images on scroll view and event fire on each image i achived it all but i have to do a extra work on it as the giving image showing that the middle image is pop out and fire event for that popout image...
i am confuse in it can anyone tell me how to achive this ....
please told me some steps to start with it..

[image: UIScrollView of Images]

Answer (score 0):

You should be implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol in the controller which should be handling the UIScrollView.

In there you will get a plethora of delegate callbacks such as when the scrollView moves or is decelerating towards a complete stop etc.
["UIScrollViewDelegate iOS reference"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)

You can implement any of the methods to suit your exact needs and modify the image's properties. To find which image is in the middle you would be comparing the contentOffset property of the scroll view o image locations.